# Rebind a JQuery function to an input field after innerHTML command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Im using JQuery to check the file size and name from an html file input field. The input field is:

```
<div id="uploadFile_div">
    <input name="source" id="imageFile" type="file" style ="border: 1px solid #576675;">
</div>
```

And the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#imageFile').bind('change', function() {

    alert("Test");
    //.... perform input checks...//

    });   
});
```

Now, I have a selection box, where the user choose between image file or video file, and based on it I send the file to different servers and also perform appropriate checks. In order to reset the input field (I do it when the user changes the selection box from Video to Image and vise versa) I use this JavaScript trick:

```
document.getElementById('uploadFile_div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('uploadFile_div').innerHTML;
```

But After 1 execution of this JavaScript, The JQuery isn't binded and I don't see the "Test" alert when I select files.

How can i rebind the JQuery ?

Thanks.

Comment: Run the `.bind()` statement again? Where are you stuck?

Comment: How can I run it again? I'm pretty new with JQuery ;0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a delegated event handler, binding the event to the parent div:

```
$('#uploadFile_div').on('change','#imageFile', function() {
   // etc
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SfgpS/

(If you're using a version of jQuery older than 1.7 use `.delegate()` instead of `.on()`. If you're using a *really* old version of jQuery use `.live()`.)

When you rewrite the `.innerHTML` of the container that effectively erases the old input element including event handlers that were bound to it, and then creates a new input. So you could re-run your original `.bind()` statement at that point to bind a handler to the new input.

With a delegated event handler as for that syntax of `.on()` you bind the handler to the *container*, i.e., to the div in this case. Events that happen to the container's child(ren) bubble up to the container (and then right on up to the document). So in this case when a change event reaches the div jQuery checks whether it originated with an element matching the selector from the second parameter of `.on()` and if so calls the your handler function. This lets you handle events on elements that don't exist at the time you create the handler. It doesn't matter if you remove and re-add the child elements because the handler was bound to the container.

(Note that if you leave out that second parameter to `.on()` it creates a non-delegated handler just the same as `.bind()`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working perfectly with `.on`. Can you please explain why the hander was unbinded in the original code after the `innerHTML` command and is not unbinded with the current code ? I would like to understand what is happening here and not just solving the problem... Thanks again.

Comment: I see, so what is actually happening now, that we binded a handler to the container div, and because that div is **not** being deleted when we use the `innerHTML` command, the event handler is still binded after it. Am I following right ?

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much it. Google "event bubbling" for more detail. Or you can read [what Quirksmode has to say on the subject](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap the whole mess up in a function you can call both `onReady` and then whenever you want to reset the upload form?

```
var resetUpload = function() {

  document.getElementById('uploadFile_div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('uploadFile_div').innerHTML;

  $('#imageFile').bind('change', function() {
    alert("Test");
    //.... perform input checks...//
  });
}

// run on ready
$(document).ready(function () {
  resetUpload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery are you using?

You could use `.live()` or `.on()` (jQuery >= 1.7) instead of `.bind()`